# How to print a function inside class

Tags: swift, function, class

Pretty dumb question, but i really don't know how to solve this problem of mine.

For example, to print() the result of a function i do:

```
func abc(a: Int, b:Int) -> Int { 
    return a+b 
} 
print(abc(a:1,b:1))
```

And that's my question, how to print() the result of a function inside class:

```
class Solution {
    func abc(a: Int, b:Int) -> Int {
       return a+b
    }
}
```

Tried to do the same - error, also idk how to google it, i tried but got nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second snippet, the function `abc(a:b:)` is inside your `Solution` class *textually*, but conceptually, it belongs to instances ("objects") of the class. These kinds of functions are often called ["methods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29), or "member functions".

So to call it, you first need to create ("instantiate") an object of that class. In Swift, objects are instanciated by calling an [initializer](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html), like so:

```
let aNewObjectOfSolution = Solution() // Solution() shorthand for Solution.init()
```

You can then call `abc` on that object, something like:

```swift
let aNewObjectOfSolution = Solution()
let result = aNewObjectOfSolution.abc(a: 1, b: 1)
print(result)
```

Or inlined:

```swift
print(Solution().abc(a: 1, b: 1))
```

Comment: I gave you as many useful terms as I could think of, those should be good starting off keywords for further reading